# Random text changing to weird icons in both admin & front end

Tags: functions, themes, css, errors, options

Has any body had this sort of problem before. The text mainly in input field descriptions turns to weird icons see image. I have deactivated all plugins and changed themes several times but same happens. However it sometimes starts working and then will just suddenly to the same thing again. In the front end the font family is open sans which will work sometimes and then sometimes it will do the same thing you can see in the image weird icons. But when the icons appear if I turn of the set font family is will work and use the default browser font family.

[image]

Comment: Do you see any errors beside that? Have you tried turning debug on?

Comment: @TomásCot I have just started my local development and all seems okay which is why it's so strange I am trying to go through the same things to try and establish when it happens but it just seems random.

Comment: I was asking because sometimes a PHP notice or error can make the browser detect the wrong encoding. You could check the encoding the browser detects just to be sure.